# Calling a jqLite function inside a AngularJS directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite, angularjs-animation

I need to call the **jqLite** *slideToggle* function inside a **AngularJS** **directive** to animate the collapsing of each content-box.

I want to slideDown/slideUp the following div..

```
<div class="ibox-content" ng-show="!collapse">
  Content
</div>
```

..by clicking on one of these icons

```
<a class="collapse-link" >
 <i data-ng-click="toggleCollapse();" data-ng-show="collapse" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
 <i data-ng-click="toggleCollapse();" data-ng-show="!collapse" class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
</a>
```

Here is a working Plunker without without the desired slideToggle animation: [Click!](https://plnkr.co/edit/ImGVFV4hFnYNdfgItL2F?p=preview).

Any ideas?
Hope you can help..

Comment: You should add reference to the full jQuery library or use angular's animate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659729/modifying-dom-slidedown-slideup-with-angularjs-and-jquery

Comment: check this out https://plnkr.co/edit/zoURPxatyamMoW4D8Itc?p=preview this is a very very basic code, you can work around it

Comment: These are both very nice solutions. This time I will use the second one. Thank you :)